# How to get desired Tag with child Tags using lxml?

Tags: python, lxml

I have an XML file like,

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<source>
<publisher>Job App</publisher>
<publisherurl>https://jldfsfsd.jlfdfs.com/Jobs/</publisherurl>
<lastBuildDate>10-19-2015 00:00:00</lastBuildDate>
<job>
    <title><![CDATA[Barista/Sandwich Prep]]></title>
    <date><![CDATA[10-19-2015]]></date>
    <referencenumber><![CDATA[83]]></referencenumber>
    <url><![CDATA[https://test/Jobs/Job.aspx?JobPostingId=83&SourceId=3]]></url>
    <company><![CDATA[Another Cafe]]></company>
    <city><![CDATA[San Francisco]]></city>
    <state><![CDATA[California]]></state>
    <country><![CDATA[United States of America]]></country>
    <postalcode><![CDATA[94123]]></postalcode>
    <description><![CDATA[  TESTTESTTESTTESTTESTTESTTESTTEST <br> STEdsasjflsdf<p> dfjhdjlas </p>]]></description> 
</job>
<job>
    <title><![CDATA[MV Drivers]]></title>
    <date><![CDATA[01-01-1900]]></date>
    <referencenumber><![CDATA[147]]></referencenumber>
    <url><![CDATA[https://sdf.dsfs.com/Jobs/Job.aspx?JobPostingId=147&SourceId=3]]></url>
    <company><![CDATA[Papa Johns Pizza]]></company>
    <city><![CDATA[Mountain View]]></city>
    <state><![CDATA[California]]></state>
    <country><![CDATA[United States of America]]></country>
    <book><![CDATA[BOOKTEST]]></book>
    <postalcode><![CDATA[94404]]></postalcode>
    <description><![CDATA[Fun sfsf job while makingfsfup to $20/hour!]]></description>    
</job>
```

In lxml parser how to get only 2nd job tag with its child nodes means I just want to get the following data as output. Note that this is not fixed format it is depend on XML file structure.

```
      <job>
        <title><![CDATA[MV Drivers]]></title>
        <date><![CDATA[01-01-1900]]></date>
        <referencenumber><![CDATA[147]]></referencenumber>
        <url><![CDATA[https://sdf.dsfs.com/Jobs/Job.aspx?JobPostingId=147&SourceId=3]]></url>
        <company><![CDATA[Papa Johns Pizza]]></company>
        <city><![CDATA[Mountain View]]></city>
        <state><![CDATA[California]]></state>
        <country><![CDATA[United States of America]]></country>
        <postalcode><![CDATA[94404]]></postalcode>
        <description><![CDATA[Fun sfsf job while makingfsfup to $20/hour!]]></description>    
    </job>
```

Comment: It's good to show what you have tried, if you tried anything.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can iterate through the elements in your document, and extract the second `'job'` element. This is very easy using the `iter` method of the `Element` class.

```
from lxml import etree

tree = etree.parse('data.xml') #or whatever is your file name
root = tree.getroot()
job_elements = list(root.iter('job'))
```

`job_elements` is a list with all the elements tagged `'job'`, in the order of appearance in the document. Take the second one (index 1).
To print it (with all its subelements), you can use the `etree.tostring` function. This will return a binary string, so to display it nicely on the console you may need to decode it to ascii.

```
output = etree.tostring(job_elements[1], pretty_print=True)
print(output.decode('ascii'))
```

#### More details

`etree.parse()` returns an `ElementTree` object. With `getroot()` you get an `Element` object starting from the root of the `ElementTree` (`Element`s have more methods). This line is actually not needed, since you need the `iter` method and `ElementTree` has an iter method too, I added just as force of habit. However if you would do some extra manipulation of the tree, it might be useful to have the `Element` and not the `ElementTree`.

`job_elements = list(root.iter('job'))` The key is the [iter method](https://lxml.de/api/lxml.etree._Element-class.html#iter). It returns an iterator along the elements in the subtree in document order (see the linked docs for more details).

Comment: Can you explain in detail about these lines?

<br/>
`root = tree.getroot()`<br/>
`job_elements = list(root.iter('job'))`<br/>

Actually I am not an expert about lxml.

Sorry for bad formatting!!! :(

Comment: Oh!! I got the point... It is perfect and simple answer for me!